# composite type and Pointer Methods

Tags: go

i have some problems creating a own type Date based on type time.Time

i tried to create the Date type as follows:

```
type Date time.Time

func (d Date) UnmarshalJSON(buf []byte) error {
    var s string
    json.Unmarshal(buf, &s)
    t, err := time.Parse(timeLayout,s)
    d= Date(t)
    return err
}

func (d Date) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    b,_ := json.Marshal(d.Format(timeLayout))
    return b,nil
}
```

this itself works, i can store this Date as a time.Time in AppEngine Datastore.
the marshaling itself also works,
but is not working is: then when unmarshal from json, the Date d is filled with the value.
this is, as i understand right, because the unmarshalJson function create a copy of Date.

so when i change the unmarshalJson function to use a Pointer to Date 
then i cant use:

```
d=Date(t)
```

so first question, is there a solution how todo this ?

what i have done now is to rewrite the Code as follows:

```
type Date struct {
    t time.Time
}

func (d *Date) UnmarshalJSON(buf []byte) error {
    var s string
    json.Unmarshal(buf, &s)
    t, err := time.Parse(timeLayout,s)
    d.t = t
    return err
}

func (d Date) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    b,_ := json.Marshal(d.t.Format(timeLayout))
    return b,nil
}
```

this works, but in this case Date is not an extending type of time.Time its just a wrapper to a time.Time type.

is there a better solution todo this ? im still new to go.

i need this Date type, to have a Date only json formated type, because Chrome only supports the html5 type: date and not datetime.
and method overriding is not possible in go (means to override the un/marshalJson methods of type time.Time ) ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally untested code:

```
type Date time.Time

func (d *Date) UnmarshalJSON(buf []byte) error {
        var s string
        json.Unmarshal(buf, &s)
        t, err := time.Parse(timeLayout, s)
        *d = *(*Date)(&t)
        return err
}

func (d *Date) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
        b, _ := json.Marshal(d.Format(timeLayout))
        return b, nil
}
```

Comment: i tested and it works :) thanks.
so this line: `*d = *(*Date)(&t)` means
pointer d is set to : pointer of : address of t converted to pointertype Date
isnt it ?

Comment: and to be sure, the solution with wrapper (my one from question) is less efficient because i work on two types. where the solution with the conversion works on one type, and itself also always on the same object, so less memory consumption and better performance because ofno need to copy or create the types ?

Comment: `*d = *(*Date)(&t)` sets the value `d` points to with the value of `t` in a type safe way.